# Select rows in groups with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

```
             A    D          E
0   2002-01-13  3.3    Tuesday
1   2002-01-13  3.9  Wednesday
2   2002-01-13  1.9   Thursday
3   2002-01-13  9.0   Saturday
4   2002-01-14  0.9    Tuesday
5   2002-01-14  0.2  Wednesday
6   2002-01-14  5.1   Thursday
7   2002-01-14  7.0     Friday
8   2002-01-14  1.9   Saturday
9   2002-01-15  4.2    Tuesday
10  2002-01-15  6.7  Wednesday
11  2002-01-15  1.2     Friday
12  2002-01-15  0.6   Saturday
```

I have a data frame above sorted by date (column A).  Column E holds day-of-week references.  I need a new df, filtering rows by the following conditions.

- If the date has both "Thursday" AND "Friday" references (as with "2002-01-14"), I want to keep only rows with references "Wednesday" through "Saturday".
- Otherwise (case of "2002-01-13" and "2002-01-15" *A group*), keep rows with references "Tuesday" through "Saturday" (all rows in the above example).

Output should be:

```
             A    D          E
0   2002-01-13  3.3    Tuesday
1   2002-01-13  3.9  Wednesday
2   2002-01-13  1.9   Thursday
3   2002-01-13  9.0   Saturday
5   2002-01-14  0.2  Wednesday
6   2002-01-14  5.1   Thursday
7   2002-01-14  7.0     Friday
8   2002-01-14  1.9   Saturday
9   2002-01-15  4.2    Tuesday
10  2002-01-15  6.7  Wednesday
11  2002-01-15  1.2     Friday
12  2002-01-15  0.6   Saturday
```

I´ve tried:

```
m1 = (group["E"] == "Wednesday")
m2 = (group["E"] == "Thursday")

grouped = df.groupby("A")

for idx, group in grouped:

    if (m1|m2).any():
        df[idx] = group[m1|m2]
    else:
        df[idx] = group[m2]
```

Comment: Your output looks exactly similar to input data. Please check.

Comment: No, it´s different. Please read the conditions

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  In this case, build your initial data frame in the source code; then show the output you actually got.  Make sure your code runs *as posted*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this using `np.where` and `isin`:

```
df[df.groupby('A')['E']
     .transform(lambda x: np.where(x.eq('Thursday').any() & x.eq('Friday').any(),
                               x.isin(['Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']),
                               x.isin(['Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'])))]
```

Output:

```
             A    D          E
0   2002-01-13  3.3    Tuesday
1   2002-01-13  3.9  Wednesday
2   2002-01-13  1.9   Thursday
3   2002-01-13  9.0   Saturday
5   2002-01-14  0.2  Wednesday
6   2002-01-14  5.1   Thursday
7   2002-01-14  7.0     Friday
8   2002-01-14  1.9   Saturday
9   2002-01-15  4.2    Tuesday
10  2002-01-15  6.7  Wednesday
11  2002-01-15  1.2     Friday
12  2002-01-15  0.6   Saturday
```

Comment: Output should contains: "5    2002-01-14   0.2   Wednesday", since "2002-01-14" group have both "Thursday" AND "Friday" references.

Comment: Typo in solution.  Misspelled Wednesday.

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple custom function on `groupby` gets the answer:

```
# helper function
def get_grp(grp):

    # values to consider
    a = ['Thursday', 'Friday']

    # set up condition
    cond = all(True if i in grp['E'].tolist() else False for i in a)

    # check conditions
    if cond:
        return grp[grp['E'].isin(['Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'])]
    else:
        return grp[grp['E'].isin(['Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'])]

## apply function on groupby object

df = df.groupby('A',as_index=False).apply(get_grp).reset_index(drop=True)

## output
df.head(7)

    A   D   E
0   2002-01-13  3.3     Tuesday
1   2002-01-13  3.9     Wednesday
2   2002-01-13  1.9     Thursday
3   2002-01-13  9.0     Saturday
4   2002-01-14  0.2     Wednesday
5   2002-01-14  5.1     Thursday
6   2002-01-14  7.0     Friday
7   2002-01-14  1.9     Saturday
```